# T-SQL Sum top in multi group by period and mod date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to sum up 'VALUE' by level1  and need to select the top 1 VALUE of each group (level 2 to level 5) with max (mod date) within max(year_month).

EDIT: top 1 -> the most recent moddate for a year_month

```
level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 | level5 | year_month | VALUE  | moddate
123    | 222    | 333    | 444    | 555    |  201403    | 110.00 | 2014-01-05
123    | 222    | 333    | 444    | 555    |  201403    | 100.00 | 2013-12-11
123    | 222    | 333    | 444    | 777    |  201403    |  50.00 | 2014-01-01
123    | 333    | 333    | 5555   | 777    |  201401    | 200.00 | 2014-01-01
122    | 222    | 333    | 444    | 888    |  201403    |  60.00 | 2014-01-01
```

Result

```
level1   SUM
123      360
122       60
```

I had a look at various "top x in group" problem but I wasn't able to make it work for me.

The only 'solution' that i can come up with is to use a cursor and loop trough all levels but there must be a better way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what our criteria are.  what do you mean by top 1 value of each group?  You don't need a loop if you use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` in a sub-query, but I'm not sure what the criteria are.

Comment: Hm, I can't see the connection between level2-level5 and the end result. Maybe you could describe how the query comes up with `360`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select level1, SUM(value) sum
from(
  select h.level1, h.VALUE
  from Huh h 
  where year(h.moddate) = h.year_month/100
  ) x
group by level1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/057d5/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your requirements you want to sum all items level1 where moddate <= yearmonth and moddate = max(moddate)

```
 select level1, sum(value) as SUM
 FROM
 (
   select level1, value, year_month, moddate
   max(moddate) OVER (PARTITION BY level1 ORDER BY year_month DESC) as maxmoddate
   from table
 )
 WHERE moddate = maxmoddate and 
       (year(moddate)*100)+month(moddate) <= year_month
 group by level1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation and desired result are a bit contradictory (at least as far as I can interpret it), but this should follow your description of what you want. For each value of level1, it will give you the max values of level2-level5 and the sum of all values for the latest year_month that is available before a certain year_month;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT level1, year_month, 
  MAX(level2) level2, MAX(level3) level3, MAX(level4) level4, MAX(level5) level5, 
  SUM(value) [sum], 
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY level1 ORDER BY year_month DESC) rn
  FROM table1
  WHERE year_month < 201402
  GROUP BY level1, year_month
)
SELECT level1, level2, level3, level4, level5, sum FROM cte WHERE rn=1;
```

The only tricky thing is the `RANK() OVER()` which is used to find the latest month available per level1. The latest month will get a value of rn=1, which is then used to filter the values in the outer select.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4db785/1).

Comment: They want the top VALUE, not the top value. My understanding of the description is that they want the top (value of) VALUE per group of `level2, level3, level4, level5, year_month` where `year_month` is the latest year/month in the corresponding group of `level2, level3, level4, level5`.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not entirely clear, but if the example is supposed to support it then I would conclude the following:

1. You want to split the dataset into groups of `level1, level2, level3, level4, level5, year_month`.
2. You want only the groups where `year_month` is the maximum value in the corresponding super-group of `level1, level2, level3, level4, level5`.
3. From every group, you want to extract one `VALUE`.
4. The extracted `VALUE` must correspond to the latest `moddate` in the group. (My assumption here is that `moddate` values are unique within groups.)
5. Finally, you want to get the totals of the extracted values of `VALUE` per `level1`.

Here is [my attempt at a solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebd52/1):

```
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    max_year_month = MAX(year_month) OVER (PARTITION BY level1, level2, level3, level4, level5),
    max_moddate    = MAX(moddate   ) OVER (PARTITION BY level1, level2, level3, level4, level5, year_month)
  FROM dbo.atable
)
SELECT
  level1,
  total = SUM(VALUE)
FROM partitioned
WHERE year_month = max_year_month
  AND moddate = max_moddate
GROUP BY
  level1
;
```

Basically, this query uses window aggregate function `MAX` to find the latest row per group and the latest group per corresponding super-group. It then uses those results to filter the dataset, and the rest is just simple grouping and aggregation.